# NSLinguisticTagger: Filter out Specified Token Depending on Tag Type

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift4, nslinguistictagger

I am trying to filter out specific tokens based on their tags. When I run my code I get this as the output. I want to only retrieve the adjectives and have that outputted. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
Hello: NSLinguisticTag(_rawValue: Interjection)
World: NSLinguisticTag(_rawValue: Noun)
this: NSLinguisticTag(_rawValue: Determiner)
is: NSLinguisticTag(_rawValue: Verb)
my: NSLinguisticTag(_rawValue: Determiner)
main: NSLinguisticTag(_rawValue: Adjective)
goal: NSLinguisticTag(_rawValue: Noun)
```

tokenizeText(inputtedText: "Hello World this is my main goal, to take these words and figure out the adjectives, verbs and nouns")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if a `tag` is of type `.adjective` in the `enumerateTags` closure and only continue if it is:

```
let sentence = "The yellow cat hunts the little gray mouse around the block"
let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .omitPunctuation, .joinNames]
let schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemes(forLanguage: "en")
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: Int(options.rawValue))
tagger.string = sentence
tagger.enumerateTags(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: sentence.count), scheme: .nameTypeOrLexicalClass, options: options) { (tag, tokenRange, _, _) in
    guard tag == .adjective, let adjectiveRange = Range(tokenRange, in: sentence) else { return }
    let adjectiveToken = sentence[adjectiveRange]
    print(adjectiveToken)
}
```

This prints out:

> yellow
>   little
>   gray

**EDIT**

If you want the tokens of more than one tag type you could store the tokens in a dictionary with the tags as keys:

```
let sentence = "The yellow cat hunts the little gray mouse around the block"
let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .omitPunctuation, .joinNames]
let schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemes(forLanguage: "en")
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: Int(options.rawValue))
tagger.string = sentence
var tokens: [NSLinguisticTag: [String]] = [:]
tagger.enumerateTags(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: sentence.count), scheme: .nameTypeOrLexicalClass, options: options) { (tag, tokenRange, _, _) in
    guard let tag = tag, let range = Range(tokenRange, in: sentence) else { return }
    let token = String(sentence[range])
    if tokens[tag] != nil {
        tokens[tag]!.append(token)
    } else {
        tokens[tag] = [token]
    }
}
print(tokens[.adjective])
print(tokens[.noun])
```

Which prints out:

> Optional(["yellow", "little", "gray"])
>    Optional(["cat", "mouse",
>   "block"])

**EDIT#2**

If you want to be able to remove certain tags from a text you could write an extension like this:

```
extension NSLinguisticTagger {
    func eliminate(unwantedTags: [NSLinguisticTag], from text: String, options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options) -> String {
        string = text
        var textWithoutUnwantedTags = ""
        enumerateTags(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count), scheme: .nameTypeOrLexicalClass, options: options) { (tag, tokenRange, _, _) in
            guard
                let tag = tag,
                !unwantedTags.contains(tag),
                let range = Range(tokenRange, in: text)
                else { return }
            let token = String(text[range])
            textWithoutUnwantedTags += " \(token)"
        }

        return textWithoutUnwantedTags.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
let sentence = "The yellow cat hunts the little gray mouse around the block"
let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .omitPunctuation, .joinNames]
let schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemes(forLanguage: "en")
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: Int(options.rawValue))

let sentenceWithoutAdjectives = tagger.eliminate(unwantedTags: [.adjective], from: sentence, options: options)
print(sentenceWithoutAdjectives)
```

Which prints out:

> The cat hunts the mouse around the block

Comment: So what happens if I want to add nouns verbs etc? Isn’t there a way to add the text into a map and pull out the text accordingly? Or would I just have to do that for all tags I want to pull out ?

Comment: Unfortunatly you cannot apply a `filter` or `map` directly to the tags because of the block based implementation of `NSLingusticTagger`. But you could enumerate once and store the tokens according to the tags. Please have a look at the edited answer for an example.

Comment: Apologies for all the questions. Basically my goal is to print out the sentence Eliminating certain token associated with tags. So hypothetically with the sentence you had, if I wanted to take out the adjectives, the sentence would print everything but yellow little gray.

Comment: That’s exactly it. If I want to exclude nouns too, can I pass nouns in under the unwanted tag parameter?

Comment: Sure, you can filter out any tags you want. Just put them in the `unwantedTags` array parameter. You can also filter out multiple tags at once. For example this filters out nouns and adjectives: `tagger.eliminate(unwantedTags: [.adjective, .noun], from: sentence, options: options)`

Comment: Okay last question, Then everything is great ! I am coming from a another language, and just started trying to pick up swift within the last few weeks. Why do I need an extension? It seems like it is just a function? Also, why do I need it before I set the option, schemes, and tagged properties? I could just do this within the function if I wanted correct?

Comment: You could also use a simple function. But when you use an extension all `NSLinguisticTagger` objects will automatically get that functionality. Using the extension becomes handy when you use more than one instance of `NSLinguisticTagger` in your app.

Comment: Okay so extension behaves the same as a class? Also, This was great help I appreciate everything!

Comment: No an extension is not a class it is used to extend a class with additional functionality without the need to subclass the class. Glad I could help!

Comment: Ahhh alright. Perfect! Thank you again for everything